# Getting value of object item in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following thing named `offer`

Image here:

[image]

I want to get the value of `assetid` in `items_to_give`.
I can get the value of `steamid_other` by `offer.steamid_other`.
However, `offer.items_to_give.assedid` comes as undefined.

How can I access that? (get it's value)

Comment: `offer.items_to_give` is  an array; therefore you need to do *something* like this: `offer.items_to_give[0].assedid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

items_to_give is an array you should try this

```
offer.items_to_give[0].assetid
```